# Laravel: binding a model to a request inside a before filter for authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

Imagine I have this route:

`POST sub.domain.tld/user/{user_id}/order`

This creates a new order for user with id `user_id`.

I then conveniently bind the User model to the route using:

`Route::model('user_id', 'User');`

So in my OrderController I can do:

`public function storeByUser(User $user)`

but there is one more requirement: the user needs to be authenticated as himself, therefore I would like to define an auth filter like so:

```
//create an order for given user by id
Route::post('/user/{user_id}/order', array('before' => 'auth'), 'OrderController@storeByUser')
->where('user_id', '[0-9]+');
```

But the issue is in the implementation of the auth filter:

```
Route::filter('auth', function(User $user)
{
    //check if $user->id is equal to Auth::user()->id
});
```

Unfortunately the above is not possible, because a filter only has the parameters `$route` and `$request`.

How can I pass the model binding (User) to the auth filter to implement such an authentication scheme?

Answer (score 1):

They fixed this in Laravel 5 with middleware, you simply make this your Controller subclass constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

The result is only authorised users can access any of the methods in this controller.

That being said, to solve your current example it isn't clear if you want users to be able to create orders for other users. If this is not the case then you don't even need the user_id param and just save the order using the user that is Auth::user().

Comment: Thanks, but what about Laravel 4? I do want to allow users (most notably admin users) to create orders for other users in the future. If they are not admins, I need to check if `$user->id == Auth->user()->id`.